# Chrome app vs extension? What else allows access to the tabs open in the browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm making an app that requires access to the tabs the user has open at the time. I haven't found a way to access this information without deploying my app using Chrome itself.
However, making an extension limits the UI severely (and my app requires a nice, organized UI). However, I understand Chrome apps are about to be discontinues. What other alternative do I have?

Comment: What specific UI limits are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome offers extensions as a way to gain access to the internals of the Chrome browser. As mentioned, apps are being discontinued. You can no longer publish new apps which are not specifically for Chrome OS. There are no other API alternatives to gain direct access to the internals of Chrome.

As with any program that is running on a multiprocess operating system or windowing system, your application can use OS and windowing system specific methodologies to snoop on other processes/windows. How to do that is OS/windowing system specific and is *way* beyond a single Stack Overflow question/answer. However, there is an alternative available that is specifically intended for the case which you describe.

### Use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging)

For what you want: Access to internal Chrome information (e.g. the open tabs) while maintaining full control of your user interface (to the extent available in your OS of choice), the documented methodology available to you is to use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). You will need to create a Chrome extension to provide access to Chrome internal information. You can communicate that information to the OS native application, which you also create, using the native messaging API. As with most such APIs, it is just a communications channel. You will need to create a message format/protocol which covers your needs.